# Java JDBC SQL Query Result Inconsistency

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Submitting a query from SQLiteStudio returns the expected result from a View.
However, when the same query is sent from my program in java, the result is different for some queries.

ie: SELECT Rev FROM PartRevs WHERE PartNumber = '800111'

This returns the expected result of **"B"** when executed within SQLiteStudio. However, then the same query is executed from JAVA, it returns **"A"**. Only one result is returned with both queries.

This does not happen consistently. Most queries work, but it occasionally does not work.

[image: Picture of 'PartRevs' View within SQLiteStudio]

[image: Picture of DDL for the 'PartRevs' View]

The 'Rev' or Revision of a given part is pulled from another table called 'ECO_TDA_Linewise'. Each time a new revision is released for a given part, a new line is added with increasing index numbers.

[image: Picture of 'ECO_TDA_Linewise' Table]

I believe the problem comes from the way the 'PartRevs' view works. Of the many other tables and queries, this is the only one that has an issue.

Here are the code blocks that interact with the database:

```
public String GetRevision(String PartNumber) {
        String sqlStatement = "SELECT Rev FROM PartRevs WHERE PartNumber = '" + PartNumber + "'";
        return getDatabaseResult(sqlStatement, "Rev");
    }
```

```
public String getDatabaseResult(String sqlStatement, String Column) {
        String result = "";
        try (Connection conn = FulfillmentWorkorders.connect();
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStatement)) {

            result = rs.getString(Column);
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("\"" + sqlStatement + "\" throws exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: How many entries do you have in your jdbc resultset for that partnumber? Can you show your java code where you extract the result from the set?

Comment: Just one entry in the result set, good question though, I did test that as an issue. I've also added the code.

Comment: Problems like this are usually the result of querying a **different** database than the one you query in the other program. BTW: Concatenating values into a query string is a bad practice: it makes your SQL vulnerable to SQL injection. Please learn about prepared statements and parameters.

Comment: Also, the code you currently have is invalid JDBC: you never call `rs.next()` before attempting `rs.getString(Column)`, so the result set is positioned **before** the first row. A JDBC-compliant driver would throw an exception in this case. Is it possible that maybe your query produced an exception and some other part of your program defaults to showing `A`?

Comment: You are concatenating strings in your query. Don't.